# In Polymer 1 how can I wrap a distributed template with another element?

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, templating

I have a custom element (let's say `my-view`) which receives as effective children a template with some annotations for the data binding.

How can I wrap the distributed template with another custom element, let's say `paper-item`?

This is my working code.

```
<my-view>
    <template>[[ item.name ]]</template>
</my-view>
```

Inside `my-view` I have

```
<template id="Repeater" is="dom-repeat">
</template>
```

and

```
_templatize() {
    const repeater = this.$.Repeater
    const template = this.queryEffectiveChildren('template')

    repeater.templatize(template)
}
```

What I want to achieve is wrapping the `template` effective children with another custom element (let's say `paper-item`).

Something like

```
_templatize() {
    const repeater = this.$.Repeater
    const template = this.queryEffectiveChildren('template')

    const item = this.create('paper-item')
    item.appendChild(template.content)

    repeater.templatize(item)
}
```

which of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I understood you wrong, but you don't create a page structure like the example you gave. Use the HTML elements first, and spice it up with javascript, if needed.

```
<dom-module id="my-view">

  <template>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[anArrayWithStrings]]" as="someValue">
      <paper-item>[[someValue]]</paper-item>
    </template>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[anArrayWithObjects]]" as="employee">
      <paper-item two-line>
        <div>[[employee.name]]</div>
        <div>[[employee.title]]</div>
      </paper-item>
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view',

      properties: {
        anArrayWithStrings: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() { return ['firstOne', 'secondOne', 'thirdOne']; }
       },

       anArrayWithObjects: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() { return [
             {'name': 'Sarah',  'title': 'accountant'},
             {'name': 'Ingrid', 'title': 'engineer'} ]; }
          },
     },

    ready: function() {
      //enter code here
    },

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I just wrote this on freehand, without testing, so there could be some faulty code in there, but this is an example of how it could look like.